# Pascal's Identity and Trees

Tags: graph-theory, applications, trees

Pascal's Identity states that $n \choose k$ = $n-1 \choose k-1$ + $n-1 \choose k$ since if one element is separated from the rest we can claim that either it is chosen (resulting in $k-1$ elements left to choose from) or it is not (resulting in $k$ elements).  We can then take either of the two terms in the identity and apply the same reasoning so that it becomes $n \choose k$ = $n-2 \choose k-2$ + $n-2 \choose k-1$ + $n-1 \choose k$.  Continuing this reasoning seems to mimic choosing paths in a decision tree with a finite depth that depends entirely on the initial n and k values.  Is this something that has been written about or explored in any books on applied combinatorics or graph theory?

Comment: It's all interations of the identity, nothing more!

Comment: and in a sense, if you're at the $k$th positition of the Pascal's triangle, you end up getting all the routes to edges of the triangle.